# Is it correct to say "I went to the US for school"?

Tags: grammar

I want to say "I went to the US to study at a university", but it sounds too formal/long, can I just say "I went to the US for school" instead?

Comment: It's true that, while "school" in the abstract means all levels of education, it *is* often used specifically to refer to university. It's up to you how precise you want to be.

Comment: In Britain, "school" is very rarely used to refer to a university.

Comment: @KillingTime Which is precisely why they went to school in the US instead.  :)

Comment: It depends on your audience. In the U.S. itself, it would be more common to say that you went somewhere for *college*.  The word *university* is used in the U.S., but not in quite the same way as people use it in other English-speaking countries.

Comment: In Canadian English people speak of going to university, but in American English it's much more common for them to speak of going to college, even if the school calls itself a university.  In Canadian English the word *college* typically refers either to a community college or to a college federated within a university. The latter example seems to be modeled on a similar  arrangement in universities in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing **grammatically** wrong with saying

> I went to the US for school

but it is not idiomatic in American English.

One reason is that “school” is too general a term.

> I went to grade school in the US.

> I went to high school in the US.

> Before college, I went to school in the US.

> I went to college in the US.

> I went to graduate school in the US.

The default assumption in the US is that you were either exclusively educated in the US or exclusively educated outside of the US. If your education was split between countries, what is idiomatic is to clarify how it was split.

Another issue is what “school” means. That is age and class dependent. Two lawyers being introduced may mean graduate schools of law by the word “school.” Two guys meeting in a local blue-collar bar may mean “public high school.” Two apparently affluent students at the same college may mean “private secondary school.”

In short, in the US, “university” may sound pretentious, and “school” may be vague or ambiguous. The idioms in Britain appear quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The more idiomatic way to say this might be "I went to college in the United States" or "I took undergrad in the U.S.A."  If you completed a degree, it might instead be something like "I got my degree in America" or "I earned my master's in the U.S."

The phrase "went to college" is an idiomatic use of the word "went" that refers to the whole undertaking of attaining one's degree, not merely or literally "going to a place".

"School" is perhaps a bit vague, as it can refer to high school, primary school, or cooking school, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's more idiomatic to say "I went to school in the US" instead of ""I went to the US for school."